# How to Implement Phone call permission granted method in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-permissions, user-permissions

In my app I have created a method named call_action method which supports the runtime permission to allow user make a phone call. I have implemented this method inside a fragment class. Now in my app I have used this method several times into activities and fragments. I know in this way I have to write this code several times inside each fragments and activities. But I would like to create a class with this method, by which I can call this method inside activities and  fragments. As I am very new in android developing as well as software developing. I am not getting the logic how to do that. here is my code which I have implemented inside Fragments

```
public class OptionMenuFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


private String phoneNumber, email;

public OptionMenuFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.option_main_fragment, container, false);

    Button myColleagues=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.myColleagues);
    myColleagues.setOnClickListener(this);
    ......
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.myColleagues:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyColleaguesPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.news:
           ......
            break;
    }
}

private void showFirstDialog() {

    //Create a new builder and get the layout.
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
   ......

    alertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;

            if (itemPosition == 0) {
                alert.dismiss();
                showSecondDialog(0);
            }

           .......
            else if (itemPosition == 5) {
                alert.dismiss();
                showSecondDialog(5);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showSecondDialog(int position) {

    alertTitle.setText("What do you want to do");
    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contact_way);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
            R.layout.first_alertlist_textstyle, android.R.id.text1, values);
    alertListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    alertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            phoneNumber = "123456";
            email="mail.com";
            break;
       ......
        case 5:
            phoneNumber = "+1233";
            email="mail.com";

    }
    alertListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition = position;


            if (itemPosition == 0) {

                alert.dismiss();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                builder.setTitle("calling to " + phoneNumber);
                //builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // close the dialog, go to login page
                        if (isPermissionGranted()) {
                            call_action(); //here I am calling call method
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do nothing
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
            if (itemPosition == 1) {
                ..

            }
            if (itemPosition == 2) {
             ....
}

//This code I want to implement into seperate class

 public void call_action(){

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    startActivity(callIntent);
 }
  public  boolean isPermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}

 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                call_action();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this

```
public class Permissions {
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;



      public  Permissions(Context context, Activity mActivity){

            this.mContext=context;
            this.mActivity=mActivity;
        }

 public void call_action(){

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
    mContext.startActivity(callIntent);
 }

    public  boolean isPermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
                mActivity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }

    }
```

And you have to keep this method in the activity or Fragment from which you are requesting permission

```
 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
```

Use it like this in Activity

```
Permissions p=new Permissions(this,this);
        p.isPermissionGranted();
```

And in case of Fragments,

```
Permissions p=new Permissions(getActivity(),getActivity());
        p.isPermissionGranted();
```

Comment: @Aris Aslam thank you very much. I will try this one and let you know

Comment: I am getting error for startActivity in Permisiions class. what shall I do here?

Comment: my bad use it like this 

`public void call_action(){

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        if(isPermissionGranted())
       mContext.startActivity(callIntent);
    }`

Comment: if it helped you then please upvote and accept my answer

Comment: I have some confusion. where can I write this line of code Permissions p=new Permissions(getActivity(),getActivity());
        p.isPermissionGranted(); and how can I get this call method inside   if (itemPosition == 0) {call_action();} like this

Comment: Write  `Permissions p=new Permissions(getActivity(),getActivity());` inside your Class just above the onCreate method
 and then use it where ever u want to like `p.isPermissionGranted();`
same way u can call the method `if (itemPosition == 0) {p.call_action();}`